# Placing UIBarButtonItem on storyboard does not appear when run

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

Placing a button on the nav bar of a UIViewController (created by xcode when I added a UITabBarController) looks great on the storyboard, but does not appear when run.

However, adding the button using the following code works fine:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"About"
            style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}
```

Thanks in advance.